Using dimens in floating point expressions
In my testing with l3benchmark, wrapping dimens and dimen expressions within a floating point expression is always faster with \dim_to_decimal:n than with \dim_to_fp:n. Yet, in kernel code, particularly l3box, I see \dim_to_fp:n used instead of \dim_to_decimal:n.
I have two questions: (1) Why is the slower \dim_to_fp:n preferred over the faster \dim_to_decimal:n in floating point expressions? (2) Which function should expl3 programmers prefer?
I provide a MWE of benchmarking \dim_to_fp:n versus \dim_to_decimal:n: For comparison's sake, I also include inputting the dimen or dimen expression directly into the floating point expression.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3benchmark}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{geometry}


\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% testing with explicit dimen value
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 15pt }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 15pt }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_fp:n { 15pt } }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_fp:n { 15pt } }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_decimal:n { 15pt } }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_decimal:n { 15pt } }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\bigskip
% testing with dimen variable
\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { 15pt }
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \l_tmpa_dim }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \l_tmpa_dim }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_fp:n { \l_tmpa_dim } }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_fp:n { \l_tmpa_dim } }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_decimal:n { \l_tmpa_dim } }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_decimal:n { \l_tmpa_dim } }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp

% same as above, but with new value of 12bp

% testing with explicit dimen value
\par
\bigskip
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 12bp }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 12bp }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_fp:n { 12bp } }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_fp:n { 12bp } }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_decimal:n { 12bp } }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_decimal:n { 12bp } }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\bigskip
% testing with dimen variable
\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { 12bp }
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \l_tmpa_dim }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \l_tmpa_dim }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_fp:n { \l_tmpa_dim } }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_fp:n { \l_tmpa_dim } }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\par
\benchmark:n
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_decimal:n { \l_tmpa_dim } }
  }
Code:~ \verb|\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \dim_to_decimal:n { \l_tmpa_dim } }|
\par
Benchmark:~ \fp_to_scientific:N \g_benchmark_time_fp
\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}


\dim_to_decimal isn't floating point it's etex \dimexpr  so a fixed point  (roughtly 5dp) evaluation followed by removing pt so it is a very fast but not very featureful TeX  conversely the fp module provided IEEE floating point decimal arithmetic implemented in tex macros It's going to be much slower.

The fp module provides an IEEE 754 floating-point implementation. As such, it is intended for places where predictable, precise calculations are required and are exported out of the 'TeX sphere': for example in creating PDF rotation details. As such, the fp module is preferred for floating point work generally.
The dim module uses TeX's dimen register type: \dim_to_decimal:n simply makes the internal data usable in a 'friendly' form. This is therefore intended for places that TeX uses dimens or where dimens are being output 'directly' - there is a limit to precision. This means that \dim_to_decimal:n is not really used in the kernel code.

There's a reason Bruno (and to a lesser extent I) worked very hard on the fp code :)
